# jQuery not removing underline for appended items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgU75/2/)**

**html:**

```
<div id = 'box' class = 'hide'>

    <button id = 'add'>add</button>

    <div class = 'entry'>
        <input type = 'text' class = 'name' placeholder = 'name'>
        <input type = 'text' class = 'email' placeholder = 'email'>
    </div>

</div>
```

**js:**

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#box").append("<div class = 'entry'>"
                     + "<input type='text' class='name' placeholder='name' spellcheck='false'></input>" 
                     + "<input type='text' class='email' placeholder='email' spellcheck='false'></input>"
                     + "</div>");
});

$('#box .entry input[type=text]').blur(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).css('border-bottom', '3px solid transparent');
    } else {
        $(this).css({
            borderBottom: '3px solid blue'
        });
    }
});
```

An input box gets underlined on blur if it's blank. This effect isn't being applied to the newly appended inputs though. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use event delegation.

Use [`.on();`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Do this:

```
$('box').on('blur','#box .entry input[type=text]',function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).css('border-bottom', '3px solid transparent');
    } else {
        $(this).css({
            borderBottom: '3px solid blue'
        });
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kgU75/4/)

`.blur()` is attach and forget while `.on()` is  dynamic.

Comment: This piece of code will listen to all blur event in the document. The correct way to do that is to insert the input elements in a form and add the blur listener on the form element. Because apart from document, form elements can listen to blur element.

Comment: @user2975123, I've reduced the scope now.

Comment: sorry my bad, blur and mouseout cannot be listened from a form. Anyway I stick to the suggestion of putting input in a form.

Comment: @AmitJoki could you explain the concept of attach and forget vs dynamic a bit more? Do you mean blur only gets applied to match elements on load and then stops, when .on constantly checks for new elements that match?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will scan the document once on page load to attach events, but in order to keep track of new elements you will need to use the .on() method:

```
$('document').on('blur', '#box .entry input[type=text]', function() {
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to rebind `blur()` to newly appended elements also.

```
<script>

rebind_blur();
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#box").append("<div class = 'entry'>"
                 + "<input type='text' class='name' placeholder='name' spellcheck='false'></input>" 
                 + "<input type='text' class='email' placeholder='email' spellcheck='false'></input>"
                 + "</div>");

    rebind_blur();
});

function rebind_blur(){
    $('#box .entry input[type=text]').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            $(this).css('border-bottom', '3px solid transparent');
        } else {
            $(this).css({
                borderBottom: '3px solid blue'
            });
        }
    });

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgU75/2/)